# Merge two rows of a file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a input file which has large data in below pattern. some part of data is shown below:

```
Data1 
C
In;
CP
In;
D
In;
Q
Out;
Data2 
CP
In;
D
In;
Q
Out;
Data3 
CP
In;
CPN
In;
D
In;
QN
Out;
```

I want my output as

```
Data1(C,CP,D,Q)
In C;
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data2 (CP,D,Q)
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data3 (CP,CPN,D,QN)
In CP;
In CPN
In D
Out QN;
```

I tried code given in comment section below, But getting error. Corrections are welcome.

Comment: Hello Neha, I saw in @Cyrus sir's answer you commented that you want solution now in Python. Sorry but this is NOT how Stack overflow works. OP(original poster) asks question with their efforts in a specific language to get guidance and asking questions over your very first question is NOT encouraged at all, for separate question open separate posts please. One question per post only please.

Comment: Also try to let users know about their answers how they were, either they working or not working, because people spending time in providing guidance in free is something special you see in this forum, cheers and happy learning on SO.

Comment: The command under `I tried code` is clearly invalid syntax (it's got mismatched double quotes and missing single quotes), see the answers you got for valid syntax. Also, never just say `But getting error` or similar - always **show** any error message you're getting by copy/pasting it into your question, just like with your code.

Comment: I executed your code @RavinderSingh13 but there also I am getting syntax error.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, could you please do let me know how are you running this code? I mean on terminal or in a script?

Comment: On script.@Ravindersingh13

Answer (score 3):

variation on @EdMorton suggestion - fixing the desired order of fields:

```sh
$ awk 'FNR==1{print;next}!(NR%2){a=$0; next} {printf "%s %s%s%s", $1,a,FS,ORS}' FS=';' file
Data
In A1;
In A2;
Out Z;
```

Comment: Error which i am getting :                                               awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==1{print;next}!(NR%2){a=sh; 
         next} {printf %s

awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error

awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==1{print;next}!(NR%2){a=sh; 
       next} {printf %s

awk: cmd. line:1: ^ unexpected newline or end of string      . Can you please tell why I am getting so

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR%2{print sep $0; sep=OFS; next} {printf "%s", $0}' file
Data
A1 In;
A2 In;
Z Out;
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried this. But I am getting syntax error pointing at "%s"

Comment: Then you're doing something other than what I showed in my answer, I don't know what as I can't see your terminal.

Comment: Error which I am getting :-      ```awk: cmd. line:1: NR%2{print sep tcsh; sep=OFS; next} {printf %s, tcsh}
 awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error```

Comment: Again, without seeing the actual command you're executing there's not much I can do to help but what you're executing looks like the command in that error message then that's missing all the necessary quotes but idk if that's just because it's an error message or because you copy/pasted it into a comment or because of markdown mangling or because the shell has expanded variables or something else. Why not simply copy/paste the script in my answer as-is and run it instead of doing whatever it is you're doing?

Comment: I see you already accepted an answer though so why bother asking questions of the rest of us whose answers you aren't going to use anyway?

Comment: I used that on script but getting syntax error ehen I am executing. The error is in command  line  to highlight I wrote it to be displayed in form of code. Other answers also have syntax error. I did not get my answer yet

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY "Other answers also have syntax error" leads me to believe that you copy/pasted the suggestions incorrectly. You're missing single quotes as argument to awk: ```awk 'whatever awk code' whateverFollows```

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY Not sure what else we can do for you - the command in my answer will not fail as you say it does, the command you copy/pasted into your comment saying it failed is not the same command that is in my answer, and the command at the end of your question will fail due to the obvious syntax errors with missing single quotes and unmatched double quotes as I mentioned in a comment under your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
val{
  sub(/;$/,OFS val"&")
  print
  val=""
  next
}
{
  val=$0
}
END{
  if(val!=""){
    print val
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Issues in OP's attempt:***

***1st:*** `awk` code should be covered in `'` so `"$1=="A1"` should be changed to `'$1=="A1"`.

***2nd:*** But condition for logic looking wrong to me because if we only looking specifically for `A1` and `In` then other lines like `Z` and `out` will miss out, hence came up with above approach.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                   ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  print                   ##Printing current line here.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
val{                      ##Checking condition if val is NOT NULL then do following.
  sub(/;$/,OFS val"&")    ##Substituting last semi colon with OFS val and semi colon here.
  print                   ##printing current line here.
  val=""                  ##Nullify val here.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=$0                  ##Setting current line value to val here.
}
END{                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(val!=""){            ##Checking condition if val is NOT NULL then do following.
    print val             ##Printing val here.
  }
}' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

and variation on @vgersh99 but setting  `FS` twice: at the beginning and at the end.

```
awk -v FS='\n' -v RS=  '                                                   
{
gsub(";", " ");
r2= $3 $2;
r3= $5 $4;
r4= $7 $6;
}
{print $1}
{print r2 FS}
{print r3 FS}
{print r4 FS}'  FS=';'  file

Data
In A1;
In A2;
Out Z;
'''

Does it give you error?
```

Comment: It worked if the 1 data set, if I have many data set . How can I do then. Question has been edited.

Comment: @NEHA CHOUDHARY This code is not for the new data set you've posted. It's only for the old data.

Comment: Can you help me out with this data