# Represent output in certain pattern

Tags: shell, awk

I have file with input data in form

```
cell1
C
input;
Cp
input;
D
input;
Q
output;
Qn
output;
cell2 
Cp
input;
D
input;
Q
output;
cell3 
A1
input;
B
input;
B1
input;
S
output;
Sn
output;
```

I want my output data as below

```
cell1
input C;
input CP;
input D;
output Q;
output Qn;
cell2 
input CP;
input D;
output Q;
cell3 
input A1;
input B;
input B1;
output S;
output Sn;
```

I used the code

```
awk -vRS='\noutput;\n' '{printf("%s\n",$1); for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2)printf("input %s;\n",$i); printf("output %s;\n",$NF)}' file
```

This code worked fine when Data has only one output line present . If data has two output line present in it , then how can I modify the code.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334351/merge-two-rows-of-a-file

Comment: That code worked only when we have only one output statement.  But in this question how can I modify code as here two output statements are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple awk

```
$ awk -F";" ' /^cell/ { print ; next } { a=$1; getline; print $1, a ";" } ' nehac.txt
cell1
input C;
input Cp;
input D;
output Q;
output Qn;
cell2
input Cp;
input D;
output Q;
cell3
input A1;
input B;
input B1;
output S;
output Sn;
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Completely based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`(though should work in any `awk` but tested it in GNU one)

```
awk '
/^cell/{
  print
  count=""
  next
}
++count==1{
  val=$0
  next
}
count==2{
  sub(/;$/,OFS val"&")
  print
  val=count=""
}' Input_file
```

To save output into Input_file itself try following.

```
awk '
/^cell/{
  print
  count=""
  next
}
++count==1{
  val=$0
  next
}
count==2{
  sub(/;$/,OFS val"&")
  print
  val=count=""
}' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
/^cell/{                ##Checking condition if line starts from cell then do following.
  print                 ##Printing current line here.
  count=""              ##Nullifying count here.
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
++count==1{             ##Checking condition if count is 1 then do following.
  val=$0                ##Assigning $0 to val now.
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
count==2{               ##Checking condition if count is 2 then do following.
  sub(/;$/,OFS val"&")  ##Substituting last semi colon in line with OFS val and ; itself here.
  print                 ##Printing current line here.
  val=count=""          ##Nullifying values here.
}' Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: can you please add the code here for seeing the output in input file only that temp mv command

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, please check solution now, added it there. That will perform inplace editing(means save output into Input_file itself).

Comment: I checked the code again. But there is one issue I am getting the desired output only if I run the code twice. I am running it inside a script.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, not sure how you are running it, run it on command line(unix/linux terminal) and see if that works on Input_file or not?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one.

```
$ awk '
/^cell/                   # just output cell*
/^(input|output)/ {       # input and output special treatment
    sub(/.$/, " " p "&")  # this probably causes problems if your
    print                 # data is different from the sample
    next
}
{
    p=$0                   # oythers get buffered
}' file
```

Output:

```
cell1
input C;
input Cp;
input D;
output Q;
output Qn;
cell2 
input Cp;
input D;
output Q;
cell3 
input A1;
input B;
input B1;
output S;
output Sn;
```

Comment: yes its getting problem as file is large and has data in other format also. Executing above code i am getting only input output not there values

Comment: my above code worked fine.. can you help to modify that only so that it give proper output when has two output statements in file

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `gnu awk` to achieve same:

```sh
awk -v RS='\n(input|output);\n' '{
   b=1
   if ($1 ~ /^cell[0-9]/) {
      print $1
      ++b
   } 
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i)
      printf "%s", gensub(/;\n$/, " " $i "&", "1", substr(RT,2))
}' file
```

```
cell1
input C;
input Cp;
input D;
output Q;
output Qn;
cell2
input Cp;
input D;
output Q;
cell3
input A1;
input B;
input B1;
output S;
output Sn;
```